# college tuition calculator in visual basic

Tags: http, post, get, request

I am trying to help my son that is in a virtual visual basic class. He has to calculate a college tuition calculator where you choose 3 colleges and add that to a list box which has been done. we have the combo box loaded with credit hours from 3-16 and there is a lbl that will display the price and a button that is to calculate the credit hours time the price that the school charges per credit hour. The prices per college credit hour is to be different per each one listed and when you run the code you choose the college and how many credit hours you want and it should display the price. I am unsure of how to set the price per each college in the code because each price has to be different. They have not gone over this in the videos or power points so it is something we have to research and find which I have been unable to.

Comment: Is there anyone that can help with this question. I have my list and variables set.            
 Dim intCredits As Integer = cboCollegeCredits.Text
        Dim intPrice As Integer = "400, 450, 500"
        Dim strCreditsType As String = " "
        Static strDisplay As String
        Dim Cost As Integer = " "
        Cost = intPrice * intCredits

Comment: okay if there is no help for the problem does anyone here know a good place to get help with tutoring in visual basic. Thanks